# How do I read an acpidump in OpenBSD?

Tags: openbsd, acpi

The [`acpidump`](http://bxr.su/OpenBSD/usr.sbin/acpidump/) utility used to provide human-readable decoding of the DSDT data, however, it seems like this is no longer available in the recent version of OpenBSD.

It looks like the last release with this functionality was [4.7](http://mdoc.su/o47/acpidump), with [4.8](http://mdoc.su/o48/acpidump) no longer having the `-f` option.  What gives?

How is one supposed to see what's in ACPI DSDT now?  (I see there's an [acpica](http://ports.su/devel/acpica) port, but it doesn't seem to have an `acpidump` command.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the newly updated [`man 8 acpidump`](http://mdoc.su/o/acpidump.8) in OpenBSD 5.5-current:

```
$ sudo pkg_add acpica
$ sudo acpidump -o /tmp/mydump
$ iasl -d /tmp/mydump.DSDT.2
$ less /tmp/mydump.DSDT.dsl
```

Note that in your case that might not be `<prefix>.DSDT.2`, check the files created by `acpidump`.

Comment: Yeah, brynet@ has finally added it, after I complained!